# Which surfaces embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ have only axially-symmetric sections?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Dmitry Ryabogin and I considered the following question some time ago, but got nowehere:

Let $M$ be a (smooth or algebraic) surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose that for every section $S$ (an intersection of $M$ with a hyperplane) is axially symmetric. What can be say about $M$?

Example 1: If $M$ is quadric then $S$ is quadric, therefore $S$ is axially symmetric.

Example 2: Supposed that $M$ is a rotation surface. Let $S$ be the intersection of $M$ with a hyperplane $H$. Let $H'$ be the hyperplane orthogonal to $H$ and passing through $M$'s rotation axis. Then $H\cap H'$ is the symmetry axis for $S$.

Conjecture: Any (algrbraic or smooth) surface $M$ with the property of having only axially symmetric sections is either a quadric or a rotation surface.

A hand-waving reasoning why:

Let $M$ be the algebraic surface and $S$ be the intersection with the hyperplane $H$; suppose that in $H$'s local coordinates $S$ is symmetric with respect to the $y$ axis. Then $S$ ought to be given by some equation $f(x^2,y)=0$: it's trivial to show that a term with $x$ in odd power would prevent $S$ from being symmetric with respect to $y$-axis.

Now, what happens to $f$ when we move $H$ around a little? Could we move coordinates a bit so that something like $f((x+\epsilon_x)^2,y+\epsilon_y)$ become $f'(x'^2,y')$ in new coordinates? If $\deg(f)=2$ obviously so; in case of rotation surfaces notice that they are given by $g(x^2+y^2,z)=0$. (There's obviously a gap in that reasoning though.)

It remains to figure a reasoning path for the converse, that the property that any section is given by $f(x^2,y)=0$ in local coordinates imposes rigid enough structure on $M$ that would classify $M$.

Question 1: How to make sense of the above hand-waving?

Question 2: How to translate above statements into the language of Algebraic Geometry, with divisors instead of intersections with hyperplanes, etc? What property of a divisor would translate into the corresponding section being axially-symmetric? Having an involution is not enough: there are many more surfaces with centrally-symmetric (rather than axially-symmetric) sections than the conjecture states.

Question 3: Is it possible to state the above intrinsically, w/out $M$ being embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Question 4: Can the above be approached from differential geometry viewpoint?

Comment: Given a curve defined by $p(x,y)=0$, is there an easy way to tell whether it has an axis of symmetry? Note that even the 1-d cubic analog is non-trivial: $\{x:p(x)=0\}$ is symmetric for either $p(x)=a(x-b)^2(x-c)$ or $p(x)=a(x-b)(x-c)(2x-b-c)$.

Comment: @MattF., I think the original problem has the advantage that the condition of EACH hyperplane being symmetric. That may prevent unstable symmetries, where by slight wiggling of parameters a symmetric section is no longer symmetric: even the section you choose is accidentally symmetric the neighboring section will not, unless the symmetry is stable enough (as in section of rotationally symmetric body vary smoothly with the hyperplane) or the nature of the body implies symmetry of every section (as in a quadric having only quardic sections that are always symmetric).

Comment: Agreed, but I’d still think a nice criterion for when $p(x,y)=0$ has an axis of symmetry would help.